How to use session across multiple domains for OAUTH2
Background
I've got a Azure Static Web App serving a React SPA with a connected Azure Functions backend on a custom domain (let's call it mysite.com). It uses Azure basic auth (aka EasyAuth). Now I have a VM serving Postgres and pg_tileserv. On that VM I have oauth2_proxy in front of pg_tileserv on a subdomain (tiles.mysite.com). If I open tiles.mysite.com in a browser then I can authenticate just fine and, on a standalone basis, it works.
My problem
I want to be able to fetch tiles from the VM from the webapp but I can't auth to the tileserv from the session on the main site.
What I've tried
I tried adding an iframe on my mysite.com that goes to tiles.mysite.com. The iframe will login from existing cookies without user intervention but when I fetch tiles it doesn't bring those cookies to the fetch requests so those fail (get 302).
Trying to avoid
I know I could put nginx and uvicorn on my VM and host the webapp and api there so that all the auth is in one place but I kind of like having the resource separation.
Desired Solution
I'm open to almost any other approach. I'd prefer to stay away from having to subscribe to even more Azure services (like Front Door) though. I don't mind switching from oauth2_proxy or adding nginx if that would solve my issue somehow.

Logically your web app should be able to call an API to get data. Your current architecture seems to prevent this:

The API would be placed in front of your VM / Postgres component and require an access token.

But the use of OAuth Proxy prevents that, since it is likely to reject any API request.


So I would focus on this type of approach:

Clients are always responsible for triggering user logins.

APIs serve data and only require an access token. They can return an HTTP 401 status code to instruct clients when they need to trigger a login.


A good first step might be to introduce an API gateway like NGINX, as you suggest:

Route 1 works as it does today and uses OAuth Proxy
Route 2 provides an API route to the same data

OAuth solutions usually have a prerequisite of a shared token issuer (the authorization server) used by all components. You also need to design the flow of access tokens, eg web apps often store them in cookies.
